# Rocket Chat docker-compose.yml not validating - ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, rocket.chat

When i'm trying run **docker-compose up -d** i'm getting error.
I can't figure out (I am not familiar with YAML)

I am getting this error **ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType**

I'm using the below script and the url from where i'm trying is https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/paas-deployments/aws/#set-up-docker-containers

```
 version: '2'

 services:
 rocketchat:
     image: rocket.chat:latest
     restart: unless-stopped
     volumes:
     - ./uploads:/app/uploads
     environment:
     - PORT=3000
     - ROOT_URL=https://chat.mydomainname.com
     - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/rocketchat
     - MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/local
     - Accounts_UseDNSDomainCheck=True
     depends_on:
     - mongo
     ports:
     - 3000:3000

 mongo:
     image: mongo:4.0
     restart: unless-stopped
     command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --replSet rs0 --storageEngine=mmapv1
     volumes:
     - ./data/runtime/db:/data/db
     - ./data/dump:/dump

 # this container's job is just to run the command to initialize the replica set.
 # it will run the command and remove himself (it will not stay running)
 mongo-init-replica:
     image: mongo:4.0
     command: >
       bash -c
         "for i in `seq 1 30`; do
         mongo mongo/rocketchat --eval \"
             rs.initiate({
             _id: 'rs0',
             members: [ { _id: 0, host: 'localhost:27017' } ]})\" &&
         s=$$? && break || s=$$?;
         echo \"Tried $$i times. Waiting 5 secs...\";
         sleep 5;
         done; (exit $$s)"
     depends_on:
     - mongo
```

Comment: `rocketchat:`, `mongo:`, _etc._ need to be indented one step more than `services:`.  If they're in the first column, that would cause this error.  Does putting two spaces at the start of those lines fix this?

Comment: I have added two spaces in front of rocketchat: and also mongo: , but i am getting new error now.

Comment: ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid top-level property "mongo-init-replica". Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: version, services, networks, volumes, and extensions starting with "x-".

You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.

Comment: Dear David Maze, please help me to resolve this issue as i have no knowledge on YAML.